# What are some JavaScript selectors?

Tags: programming-languages, javascript, interview

I was at an interview recently and although they knew that I was a beginner in javascript they asked me what selectors I used before? I didn't know what to say.

I came back home and searched for it but can't find a clear definition.  Isn't a selector something like a .class or #id?

Comment: There are no "JavaScript selectors".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you were interviewed by morons. Consider that bullet dodged. They were probably thinking of jQuery, which you probably should learn, but it does in fact use CSS selectors and xpath... (whatever you call xpath statements/selector thingies) for syntax. The right answer if you should want to be hired by somebody who makes the same mistake again is "JavaScript doesn't have selectors. Are you talking about jQuery? Or are you referring to the DOM API?" The DOM API, btw, is something you should already know if you don't.

Edit: Okay, maybe not total morons. They could have been thinking of the query selector API (see Dystroy's answer) but IMO, that still should have been clear.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  But I would still like to know what exactly are considered JS Selectors. Is this what they meant? http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: jQuery. They were thinking of jQuery. I added more explanation.

Comment: lol at silent down-vote. Maybe somebody who's asked that question?

Comment: Not sure who voted you down.  I voted you up.  lol

Comment: @ErikReppen I was writing a comment explaining my downvote, and then you expanded your answer to mention the DOM, at which point both my downvote and comment became irrelevant.

Comment: @AAA: w3schools is a **horrible** reference. Please do not use it for anything!

Comment: @thiefMaster Thanks, any legit source to learn more about selectors?

Comment: @AAA w3schools is a bad resource. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: The official jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @AAA [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/.

Comment: *sigh* w3schools is fine for beginners w3fools isnt even kept up to date as is, and is pretty pretentious. However [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a much better resource.

Comment: @Loktar I would say w3schools is fine for reference if it happens to have the exact method you were looking for on a google but I wouldn't advise treating it as a primary source for beginners since it tends to be dated/incomplete. On the other hand, unlike MDN which does have good info, at least the info is always there and not awaiting some wiki upgrade or other form of content-blocking foolishness.

Comment: I don't see a big problem with calling the selectors used by `querySelector` etc "javascript selectors", just like you often call selectors used in css "css selectors". May not be the most accurate use of terminology, but calling them "morons" for it is a bit over the top.

Comment: It is and I added a note. But they should have made the question more clear when he didn't get it if they were talking about the querySelector API and even if they were, wtf kind of question "what selectors have you used?" The fancier you get with selectors/xpath the more likely you're murdering performance for no good reason.

Comment: Okay, had to share the rich irony. This answer earned me an "enlightened" badge.

Answer (score 6):

Your interviewer was probably referring to the query language which lets you form selectors to find elements in the DOM using methods like [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

Note that selectors are normalized by the w3.org in [the selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) :

> Selectors, which are widely used in CSS, are patterns that match
>   against elements in a tree structure [SELECT][CSS21]. The Selectors
>   API specification defines methods for retrieving Element nodes from
>   the DOM by matching against a group of selectors. It is often
>   desirable to perform DOM operations on a specific set of elements in a
>   document. These methods simplify the process of acquiring specific
>   elements, especially compared with the more verbose techniques defined
>   and used in the past.

The purpose of the question could be to check you know those selectors exist, which would make a difference with many developers only aware of the use of libraries like jQuery and who would make the mistake of answering that JavaScript doesn't have selectors.

Comment: That's my guess too, the new(ish) Selectors API is probably what they meant.

Comment: Good point. But I guess I still think of CSS as having selectors and JS/JQ as just borrowing the syntax. If they'd asked about selector methods, it would be a lot more clear.

Comment: The API is called the **selectors API**. That's clear to me.

Comment: Still a really stupid interview question, IMO.

Comment: On that I may agree. Many good developers could very well miss what was meant by the question.

Comment: Especially since querySelector and querySelectorAll are just trivia until you've dropped IE7 support.